# Custom control / UIView in Xamarin.iOS with design-time properties

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin, uiview, xamarin.ios

I am creating a user interface for an iOS app and I am looking for the correct way to create a reusable custom control. I got it generally working when running the app, but at design time setting my "exported" properties has no visible effect in the designer. I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong, so perhaps someone could give me guidance

What I am doing:

- I have created a subclass of `UIControl`.
- In the constructor I call an `Initialize` method.
- In the `Initialize` method, I add several subviews and constraints to layout them within my control

Here is some hollowed out code that shows the above:

```
  [Register("RangedValueSelector"), DesignTimeVisible(true)]
public sealed class RangedValueSelector : UIControl
{  
    public RangedValueSelector(IntPtr p)
            : base(p)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public RangedValueSelector()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public int HorizontalButtonSpacing
    {
        get { return _horizontalButtonSpacing; }
        set
        {
            _horizontalButtonSpacing = value;
        }
    }


    [Export("LabelBoxVerticalInset"), Browsable(true)]
    public int LabelBoxVerticalInset
    {
        get
        {
            return _labelBoxVerticalInset;
        }

        set
        {
            _labelBoxVerticalInset = value;
        }
    }

      private void Initialize()
    {
        //Code that creates and add Subviews
        //Code that creates and add the required constraints, some of which should depend on the design time properties
    }
}
```

So the control works perfectly fine if I set the exported properties via the designer, however they do not have an immediate effect in the designer itself.

What is the suggested way of having design-time settable properties that change the constraint values? I would like to avoid having to recreate all the subviews each time someone in the code or in the designer sets a property.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing constructor with RectangleF which is used by designer.

> public RangedValueSelector(RectangleF bounds):base(bounds){}

The rest seems to be correct.